# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined - but console.log is showing value

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to select a div with a class name using `document.getElementsByClassName()` and a variable. However when the function fires I'm getting *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined.*
I've ran some tests with `console.log` and it's showing that the variable property is defined and that it has a value. Heres the function:

```
function openLightBox() {
 var itemId = event.target.id; 
 var lightBox = document.getElementsByClassName(itemId);

 console.log(lightBox);
 lightBox.style.display = 'block' ;
};
```

As you can see I'm logging the variable variable `lightBox` to the console and this is display the correct value. I'm confused why the last line of this function isn't working.

**UPDATE**

I was missing the fact that var `lightBox = document.getElementsByClassName(itemId);` is returning an array. The solution was very simple in the end, I simply needed to select the first element in the array by adding `[0]` after the `lightBox` variable in the last line of the function:

```
function openLightBox() {
 var itemId = event.target.id; 
 var lightBox = document.getElementsByClassName(itemId);
 console.log(lightBox);
 lightBox[0].style.display = 'block' ;
};
```

Comment: Please share the output of console.log(lightBox);

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Comment: `lightBox.style` is undefined as `lightbox` is not a DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName(itemId)` returns an array. You need iterate through the `lightBox` object.

```
for(var idx = 0; idx < lightBox.length; idx++) {
    lightBox[idx].style.display = 'block' ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Raju. I didn't end up using your code but your answer was the most helpful as it pointed out that I was missing the fact that an array was being returned. I will be updating my question to show my solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is `itemId` the id of the DOM element you're targeting? If so, you should be using `document.getElementById(itemId)`.